# Saving Multiple record related to the same Model in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, save, cakephp-2.0

I have a rating system the user should input his data in the input table for each year(All the years are listed) then he save all the input data at once, if the data is exist previously then the system should display the data in the input field so the user can update the record , if the data does not exist for the year then the input field should be empty and the system should add a new record when the user input a value in the field . 
I have some problems.the data didn't display in the input fields this is the first problem .and the second problem when I try to save data I didn't got anything new in the database.

View:

```
<table width="100%" style="font-size:12px">
    <tr>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Data Quality </th>
        <th>Reference</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
    <? foreach ($years as $year) :?>
        <tr>
            <td><? echo $year['ReportYear']['year'];?></td>
            <? echo $this->Form->create('IndicatorDatum');?>
            <? echo $this->Form->hidden('IndicatorDatum.id');?> 
            <td > <? echo $this->Form->input('IndicatorDatum.value', array('label'=> false)); ?></td>
            <td> <? echo $this->Form->input("IndicatorDatum.Assurance",array(
                    'style'=>'width:250px; display: -webkit-inline-box;', 
                    'type'=>'select',
                    'multiple'=>'checkbox',
                    'options'=>$assurances,
                    'label' => false)
                ); ?> 
            </td>
            <td><? echo $this->Form->input('IndicatorDatum.comment',array(
                    'type' => 'textarea', 
                    'escape' => false,
                    'label' => false));?>
            </td>
            <td><? echo $this->Form->input('IndicatorDatum.reference',array(
                    'type' => 'textarea', 
                    'escape' => false,
                    'label' => false));  ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <? endforeach ; ?> 
</table>
```

Controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')|| $this->request->is('put')) {
    if ($this->IndicatorDatum->saveMany($this->request->data['IndicatorDatum'])) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The indicator data has been saved'),
                 'flash/success'
            );
            $this->redirect(array(
                'action'=>'edit_group',
                $group_id
            ));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                    __('The indicator data could not be saved. Please verify the fields highlighted in red and try again.'),
                    'flash/error'
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure from your description if you are trying to create a new row in your DB table or whether you are updating already existing rows in your DB table.

Comment: I want both, if there is no existing data for the year the fields will be blank, and if there is a data that related to the year it will be in the fields.

So when the user fill the empty field that mean that he want to add a new data,
and if the user want to update the value just he will change the value in the field and click save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to give a demonstrate  to you for how to achieve  goal.  Just read the following code and try to implement as your desire.

```
// view

echo $this->Form->create('ReportYear', array('action' => 'add'));


// Use loop for multiple rows 
// Here I use 0 for only one row
    echo $this->Form->input('IndicatorDatum.0.value');
    echo $this->Form->input('IndicatorDatum.0.comment');
    echo $this->Form->input('IndicatorDatum.0.reference');


echo $this->Form->end('Save');


// in controller
public function add() {
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        // Use the following to avoid validation errors:
        unset($this->ReportYear->IndicatorDatum->validate['id']);
        $this->Company->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
    }
}
```

For Best understanding read [Saving Related Model Data (hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo) in CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto)

**update**

```
echo $this->Form->input('IndicatorDatum.0.value', array(
        'value'=>$data['IndicatorDatum'[0]['value'
    )
);
```

Here I have added a `value` attribute into input field. I just put value but you need to put proper value here which you want to see